# Flyway migration failed

Tags: java, flyway

In classpath:/db.migration have migrations `V1__Strory_create.sql` and `V2__Task_create.sql` but flyway dosen't see that and fall with msg

> 2022-05-02 17:28:07.993  INFO 45296 --- [  restartedMain]
> c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server
> at : http://localhost:8888/story 2022-05-02 17:28:08.213  INFO 45296
> --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=story, profiles=[story], label=default,
> version=null, state=null 2022-05-02 17:28:08.215  INFO 45296 --- [
> restartedMain] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located
> property source: [BootstrapPropertySource
> {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}, BootstrapPropertySource
> {name='bootstrapProperties-classpath:/config/story.yml'}] 2022-05-02
> 17:28:08:331 INFO  com.openhelp.story.StoryApplication - The following
> 1 profile is active: "default" 2022-05-02 17:28:11:368 DEBUG
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - Driver class org.postgresql.Driver
> found in Thread context class loader
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@707d8885
> 2022-05-02 17:28:11:426 ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Flyway failed to initialize: none of the following migration scripts
> locations could be found:
>
> - classpath:db/migration
>
> Action:
>
> Review the locations above or check your Flyway configuration
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Configuration fetch from config service with bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: story
  profiles:
    active: default
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${vcap.services.configserver.credentials.uri:http://localhost:8888/story}
```

And fetched config

```
server:
  port: 0

eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.uuid}
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

spring:
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: 'false'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
        generate_statistics: 'false'
        format_sql: 'true'
        use_sql_comments: 'false'
        show_sql: 'true'
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    open-in-view: 'false'
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: 'true'
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    password: '1'
    username: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/openhelp_story
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
logging:
  level:
    org:
      apache:
        tomcat:
          jdbc:
            pool: debug
        nodeValue: ERROR
      springframework:
        security: info
        nodeValue: DEBUG
      hibernate:
        nodeValue: ERROR
        jdbc: ERROR
        stat: DEBUG
        SQL: WARN
        cache: ERROR
    root: ERROR
    com:
      openhelp: debug
      zaxxer:
        hikari: debug
  pattern:
    console: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
management:
  endpoints:
    jmx:
      exposure:
        include: health
openhelp:
  logging:
    path: logs
    archive-path: logs/logs-archive
```

As we can see from log above the configuration fetched successully. Perhaps config is wrong?

Comment: Check the path for where Flyway expects to find your SQL. It's in the Flyway config. Maybe it's different than what you currently have.

Comment: This might actually refer to the directory structure of your project. In other words, something like `app/src/resources/db/migration` where 'app' is your app directory. We have ours at `/src/resource/db/migration/default`, for example. Also, "pro tip:" format your filenames starting with `V##.##__` so you can insert "fixes" like `V01.01__` etc.

Comment: @randy Do you mean instead `V1__Strory_create.sql` use `V01.01__Strory_create.sql` naming but what principal for increment first and second number? For example: next migration should be `V02.01__Task_create.sql` or `V01.02__Task_create.sql`? when we increment first number when second?

Comment: @Pavel, yes `V1.00__` and increment to `V2.00` for "normal" migrations. Fixes go in the sub-version increments as `V1.01__`, etc. So for example, say you identify an issue with `V1.00` or a related behavior, you could put the fix in as `V1.01` instead of `V3.00` where it has no context. And my apologies for the leading zeros in my examples... one quickly gets past 10 migrations and gets used to the ##.## format! 

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in `classpath:/db.migration` instead of `classpath:/db/migration`. Accidentally I'm create one folder.